# Software to Draw Laboratory Apparatus

Tags: software

So I am preparing a blog post about chemistry for lay people and I have decided to start talking about the basics. It turns out that it would be super useful to create chemical apparatus on demand to illustrate the post. Such as this one:

[image]

I particularly like the clean vector image look. This is what I am looking for. A software that allows me to assemble these vector-graphics style 2D chemical apparatus as well as let me control the color (and texture, if possible) of the contents inside the flasks.

It is meaningful that the software contains correct laboratory glassware, preferably the classical stuff that is instantly recognizable like the bunsen burners and tripods rather than heat mantles, but that is me being picky. So far, anything goes.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't find an answer here in a few days, try posting in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you, I will try that as soon as a few days pass. On the other hand, do you think it would be harmful if I had both posts going simultaneously?

Comment: though some resent cross-posting, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @urquiza: ChemDraw has a lot of templates for chemistry labs.

Comment: Likely you intend "clear" to apply to the graphic. Once you'll succeed on putting up the pics for your blog I would skip the rack and especially its joints as I am pretty sure they can be mixed up with pipes and valves.

Comment: Bitonal illustrations e.g., with ChemSketch ([demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNfH3jVAO-M), or the colorful templates from Chemdraw ([sample page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#) by the stamp icon (before last, top row)). Subscription based [chemix](https://chemix.org/) follows a little bit different approach (liquids may have adjusted colors; the meniscus adjusts if the container is tilted; export as jpeg/png/svg). But the more modern the lab is, the less often you encounter open flames (e.g., Bunsen burner) for extended heating below a flask ...

Comment: @Buttonwood That is very close to what I was thinking. The only thing is that it can't show liquids boiling, for instance. Anyway, would mind publishing it as an answer? I am thinking on accepting your answer but publishing a new question at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @urquiza In the past days, there were other priorities than chemistry.se; now I added an illustrated brief overview as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to this topic is that the typically used programs for this
tasks vary in their coverage of of lab ware to prepare such illustrations and
focus on drawing molecules, exporting molecules in machine readable (chemical)
formats understood e.g., by databases, and performing some computations (e.g.,
averaged molecular and isotopic weight).  Beside popularity of the programs if
you want to share/collaborate with colleagues intermediate files, an additional
point to consider are the graphic formats these programs offer for file I/O.
Thus, a native export of the `.svg` formats understood e.g., by
inkscape may be an advantage.

Without aim to provide an exhaustive description, the following examples may
illustrate this with templates and building a distillation.

- [ACD ChemSketch](https://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/index.php) contains quite a number of lab utensils in the template library.  The free (as in free beer) version disables some functions which however are not relevant to drawing the beakers, flasks, etc.  The representation of them did not change for decades, however the Windows program offers a native export as `.png` and `.pdf`.  Recent releases improved interaction with   [wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3917) to equally work well enough in Linux, too (this includes the current version 2021.1.3).  It may take some tinkering to adjust the the individual pieces' orientation to build a setup.

  Overview of the chemical lab utensils:
  [image]

  A distillation:

  [image]
- [ChemDraw](https://perkinelmerinformatics.com/products/research/chemdraw/)
  offers templates which may be bitonal, or in color (see, e.g., [here](http://it-mda.ru/it_DM/graph/ChemDraw/ChemDraw_template.php). Primarily written for Windows and Mac, with only varying success to be deployed in Linux, the program is widely used in academia and industry (definitively not for free as in free beer, often accessed within a campus license).  The templates include parts aligned to fit better into the round bottom flasks.  Among the export formats are `.png` and `.svg`.  The later allows you e.g., to adjust the fill and stroke of the  paths, or to remove the ace label (which actually is a trade mark of [Ace Glass](https://www.aceglass.com/), NJ).

  With many chemistry-relevant functions removed, the [ChemDraw JS page](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html) allows to get familiar with them (stamp button opens a pull-down menu), to save the   drawings in the native format (Structure -> Get .cdxml), as .png (-> Get   image) or vector file (-> get .svg).

  *Some* of the templates:

  [image]

  (image credit to a Russian [blog post](http://it-mda.ru/it_DM/graph/ChemDraw/ChemDraw_template.php))

  A distillation (color adjustments with Inkscape):

  [image]
- [ChemDoodle](https://www.chemdoodle.com/) is the youngest of these three   sketchers with the largest number of lab utensils in the template library.    Capable to interact with many chemistry-relevant file formats (including the
  public .cdxml of ChemDraw), the export of the graphics includes many options
  for round-trip edits, and export e.g., as either `.png`, or (optionally   layered) vector format (.svg, .ps, .pdf) and anticipate their use in web pages and services like twitter.  The purchase of one of their licenses offers the user to choose between a program for Windows, or Mac, or Linux; this includes the option to shuttle the license key among the operating systems.

  An overview of the chemistry templates:

  [image]

  With light retouches in inkscape, an illustration of a short-path distillation:

  [image]
- Contrasting to the programs above, [chemix](https://chemix.org/)'s focus is about drawing a lab setup exported either as bitmap or vector file.  (Maybe drawing organic structures will be added.) By number, the inventory of lab utensils (still) is smaller than e.g., the one offered in ChemDoodle, though it contains material absent in the other collections (e.g., a waterless condenser, or the GHS symbols).

  In addition to standard options to move and scale the objects, there are interesting details in handling the objects like (incomplete list):

  - joining the elements is guided by snap-points like magnets
  - both color and height of liquids in the containers may be adjusted within the interface, including boiling-like bubbles
  - a tilt of the container automatically affects the meniscus of the liquid
  - changing the height of the lab boy affects the scissoring

  The green arc sign in the illustration below mark utensils you access when entering a paid subscription.  Based on their [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/chemixlab), there is continuing development and addition of utensils for this application running remotely in your web browser.

  An illustration:

  [image]

The comparison with the utensils in the lab may reveal differences between the sets offered (e.g., Chemix' missing pressure release for a distillation present in Chemsketch and ChemDraw's sets/how you should mount safely a distillation) may be seen; thus, design with care for detail.

Comment: @Buttonwood That was a stupendous answer. However, I tried Chemix and wasn't able to put the boiling liquid mask to my fluids inside the glassware. Is that a premium feature?

Comment: @urquiza The seventh category «Accessories» contains bubbles, which equally are available in the free section. As colour, «default» seems to blend nicely if this rectangle is stashed behind the beaker/round bottom flask in question. This may require some adjustment of rows (i.e., height) and bubbles per row (i.e., width) of the «bubble rectangle» to fit for the (adjustable height) of liquid in the container (which may be moved as usual by the mouse, too).